# Thumbnails create after upload image in rails 3 without use of libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a issue to create thumbnail of uploaded image without using any libraries like paperclip or any other..  I can't find any solutions which create thumbnail without using any libraries..  Any one have a solutions then please send me asap.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ther is none. You will have to rewrite the image, so you need to use image magick or something similiar. And as this is not totally trivial, there is nothing wrong with using a gem for that.

You could of course just use the width and height tags of the image to make them appear smaller - but this really is not the way to go. The images will look crappy and you will waste bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external service. I've recently started using http://avatars.io No need for paperclip, or imagemagick or saving files to your server. I don't know how much it's going to cost when it goes live though.

Images are uploaded using some javascript which they provide, and all you need to do is save the URL they return to you.

Images can then be resized by adding "?size=small" to the url.

e.g.
 - http://avatars.io/1315Gxzkm?size=small